# UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

I would open a tableview pressing a button.
I made several attempts, according to this scheme:

```
- (IBAction)menuContext:(id)sender {
    //ViewController2 *xx = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    //ViewControllerXXX *xx = [[ViewControllerXXX alloc] init];
    ViewController2 *xx = [[ApplicationModel sharedInstance] getView2];

    UIPopoverController *over = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:xx];

    [over setDelegate: (id) self];

    [over presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated: YES];

}
```

but just clicks the button the program crashes ...

ViewController2 is a subclass of UITableViewController. I can use it on the popover?
thanks

Comment: ARC or not ? have you tried to retain over ?

Comment: r u properly setting the button action in .xib if u r using .xib

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you are not setting the selector for the button .pls make sure you do it (or) you might be setting the selector to a method which returns nil parameter